# NVidia DeepStream Output Inference Class Mismatch - "Vehicle Class"

Tags: nvidia-jetson, nvidia-deepstream

**• Hardware Platform (Jetson / GPU)**
Jetson Nano 4GB, Ubuntu 18.4

**• DeepStream Version**
marketplace.azurecr.io/nvidia/deepstream-iot2-l4t:latest

**• JetPack Version**
4.3

**• Issue Type**
Output inference class is different from Model class

**• How to reproduce the issue ?**
On DeepStream, deploy a object detection ONNX model. My model is ONNX model exported from Azure Custom Vision. My label file has 2 classes - 'Mask', 'No_Mask'. Deployment works fine and I am able to execute my model using DeepStream. However, output inference class I am getting as 'Vehicle' and  'No_Mask'. Can you please help me understand why I am getting output inference label as "Vehicle" when it is not there in my Model.

**Sample output inference log**
{"log":"    "1|324|23|380|61|Vehicle|#|||||||0"\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-01-05T16:15:15.614591738Z"}

{"log":"    "1|324|23|380|61|Vehicle|#|||||||0"\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-01-05T16:15:15.614790179Z"}

{"log":"    "2|141|15|365|161|No Mask"\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-01-05T16:15:15.614221209Z"}

Comment: Sample output inference log : {"log":"    \"1|324|23|380|61|Vehicle|#|||||||0\"\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-01-05T16:15:15.614591738Z"}

Comment: property]
gpu-id=0
net-scale-factor=1
#0=RGB, 1=BGR
model-color-format=1
onnx-file=../custom_models/cans-model.onnx
labelfile-path=../custom_models/cans-labels.txt
## 0=FP32, 1=INT8, 2=FP16 mode
network-mode=0
num-detected-classes=2
gie-unique-id=1
is-classifier=0
maintain-aspect-ratio=1
#output-blob-names=output-blob-names=coverage;bbox
parse-bbox-func-name=NvDsInferParseCustomYoloV2Tiny
custom-lib-path=../custom_models/libnvdsinfer_custom_impl_Yolo_Custom_Vision.so

Comment: [sensor0]
enable=1
type=Camera
id=in00
location=45.293701447;-75.8303914499;48.1557479338
description=Camera Sensor
coordinate=5.2;10.;11.2

Answer (score 0):

You've most probably specified wrong labels file or the classes in it are wrong. It's provided in `labelfile-path` as

```
labelfile-path=labels.txt
```

Comment: I checked label path seems to be correct. Actually the device is picking 1 label from my File and second one it does not pick from my label file. Instead it shows 'Vehicle'. This confuses me as to why it is picking selectively.

Comment: Hello,

I am using proper config files and text files. I am attaching config files. There are 3 files zipped. I am using only 1 primary GIE. I have 2 class in my ML Model and only the first class gets replaced with "Vehicle" text. Other class shows fine.

One more fact I would like to highlight. For testing purpose, I even used a model which has 3-4 classes. And what I can see is that only first class gets replaced with text "Vehicle". Other class sees t show up fine. 

Please help.

Amit

Comment: Can you confirm you've not declared any classes in your src files? Also, are you using deepstream-app or any other test app?